How to reenter previously exited pipenv environment on Windows
There is a similar thread on this, however it is on Mac. There's also another for Linux.
I am wondering how to specifically open this virtual environment again, on Windows, which is located at:
C:\Users\charl.virtualenvs\projects-QJDb9xM6
I've tried using the source command but it is not supported on Windows. I'm also unclear on what the user on the first thread meant by using the PATH.

Change directory to the root folder of your project.
cd projects

Activate the project's virtual environment.
pipenv shell

When no longer needed, deactivate your virtual environment.
exit

